# Fatal error: Call to a member function insert_product() on string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, oop

I am trying to add data to my products database using oop I am trying to pass the information to my products class and I keep getting this error Fatal error: Call to a member function insert_product() on string.

```
<?php
$product = new Product();

    $product_name = $_POST['name'];
    $product_type = $_POST['type'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $product->insert_product($product_name,$product_type,$price);



?>
```

product class

```
  <?php
class Product
{


public function insert_product($product_name,$product_type,$price)
    {
       try {




          $stmt = Database::getInstance()->getConnection()->prepare("INSERT INTO products($product_name,$product_type,$price) 
                                                       VALUES(:product_name,:product_type,:price)");

          $stmt->bindparam(":product_name", $product_name);
          $stmt->bindparam(":product_type", $product_type);
          $stmt->bindparam(":price", $price);



           $stmt->execute(); 

           return $stmt; 
       }
       catch(PDOException $e)
       {

           echo $e->getMessage();
       }    
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: `}` maybe this is causing the error or it is just a piece of an entire code?

Comment: That should not cause fatal error?

Comment: it'll throw a syntax error, but i'm in doubt now..

Comment: thats just a piece of entire code I had it in an if statement but I took it out to see if it worked and it still didnt

Comment: `insert_post`? Then why do we see `insert_product`?

Comment: The fatal error is related to **insert_post()** method, not related to **insert_product()** method. Update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: I meant to put product not post

Comment: The class declaration exists? `class Product{ /...../ }`

Comment: im auto loading all the classes in my init file all my other classes work fine

Comment: Could you paste the entire class Product here?

Comment: iv updated  my entire code

Comment: It's just the method insert_product...

Comment: Somewhere, in not showed code `$product` becomes string. So check it.